# Generate new Items / CSV-Rows in Spring Batch Processor in Batch Job

Tags: java, spring-batch, export-to-csv, itemprocessor

Summary : I need to export some CSV Files with Rows that are generated during Batch export.

I already do have an JdbcItemreader to get the Data from my DB. The Processor formats the OutputData to the required format. And i do have a basic FlatFileItemWriter that writes CSV-Files

This is what my Exported CSV-Lines look like:

```
040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;32

040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;32
```

I know that those lines look ugly but it is a requirement from the other CSV Importer.
now i need to calculate "sum lines" which and add them **before** the two rows with identical Ids.
The calculated "sum line" should look like this:

```
040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000036,00;+00000000,00;+00000036,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;31
```

So the final Output should look like This:

```
040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000036,00;+00000000,00;+00000036,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;31
040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;32   
040010;0006765;0001420;0008014;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;+00000018,00;+00000000,00;m06;100220;000014;030;CNAME;30;32
```

Here are my Questions:

- is it possible to add lines between other lines in the CSV-File via FlatFileItemWriter ? or should i generate the sum lines before i write the File ?
- is it somehow possible to access the full data chunk in the ItemWriter / Processor ? so that i can maybe add the new lines to the chunk before writing them to the file ?

Comment: I guess the number of lines for which you want to do the aggregation (sum in this case) is variable (not always 2). Do you confirm? Are those lines consecutive? What if you insert a "sum line" after processing a first chunk and then you encounter a new line with the same id in a subsequent chunk?

Comment: You are right, its not always two lines-> What if you insert a "sum line" after processing a first chunk and then you encounter a new line with the same id in a subsequent chunk?  -> that might become a problem. I guess that chunk based processing is not the way to go then... 

I guess that it might become a lot easier to use a simple Tasklet that does the whole job, especially because of the problem you mentioned.

Comment: That's where I wanted to come with my question..

Comment: I will add some details to the question once i found a proper way to handle this.